# BrowserAnimationsModule Animations of Angular 4.0.1 not working on Firefox

Tags: angular, animation

I have a couple of animations on my page. On Google Chrome is working well and on Safari (MacOS) too. On Firefox latest version (53.0) are not working and throws the following error:

```
ERROR TypeError: can't convert undefined to object
Stack trace:
WebAnimationsPlayer.prototype._captureStyles@http://192.168.1.78:8000/node_modules/@angular/animations/bundles/animations-browser.umd.js:2427:13
WebAnimationsPlayer/<@http://192.168.1.78:8000/node_modules/@angular/animations/bundles/animations-browser.umd.js:2243:26
WebAnimationsPlayer@http://192.168.1.78:8000/node_modules/@angular/animations/bundles/animations-browser.umd.js:2242:9
WebAnimationsDriver.prototype.animate@http://192.168.1.78:8000/node_modules/@angular/animations/bundles/animations-browser.umd.js:2487:16
DomAnimationEngine.prototype._buildPlayer@http://192.168.1.78:8000/node_modules/@angular/animations/bundles/animations-browser.umd.js:1544:16
DomAnimationEngine.prototype.animateTransition/players<@http://192.168.1.78:8000/node_modules/@angular/animations/bundles/animations-browser.umd.js:1490:20
DomAnimationEngine.prototype.animateTransition@http://192.168.1.78:8000/node_modules/@angular/animations/bundles/animations-browser.umd.js:1488:40
DomAnimationEngine.prototype.setProperty@http://192.168.1.78:8000/node_modules/@angular/animations/bundles/animations-browser.umd.js:1379:13
AnimationRenderer.prototype.setProperty@http://192.168.1.78:8000/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser-animations.umd.js:234:13
setElementProperty@http://192.168.1.78:8000/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:9544:5
checkAndUpdateElementValue@http://192.168.1.78:8000/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:9463:13
.
.
.
```

and continues...

If i change BrowserAnimationsModule for NoopAnimationsModule (for disable animations) it load the page wihout any problem.

This only happen on Firefox and not on Chrome or Safari.

**UPDATE 1**

Please see this plunker that i made. The result on Firefox is the same.

http://plnkr.co/edit/K2NxOn?p=preview

Any idea?

Comment: Can you reproduce it somewhere?

Comment: Done @yurzui please check it.

Comment: I see error `Animation to or from an underlying value is not yet supported` Seems is related with https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/14752